# Write this function without the global array. (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a course and I'm to return an array using .filter from an array of strings.

```js
arr = ['tim','tom','taaaaaamy'];

const validUserNames = arr.filter(n => n.length < 10); 

console.log(validUserNames);
```

While this works, the course does not let me use a global variable. How would I write this without declaring the array initially? Thanks.

Comment: `['tim','tom','taaaaaamy'].filter(` ?

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice your requirements:

```
const validUserNames = (arr) => arr.filter(n => n.length < 10); 
validUserNames(['tim','tom','taaaaaamy'])
```

Keep in mind that all values in your array actually have less then 10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Since the goal is to create a function "validUserNames" that can be used on some array of strings, returning an array of only the *valid* strings, you need a function that accepts a *parameter*, which is the array that the caller wants filtered.

The traditional/classic format declares and names the parameters in the *function* statement:

```
function validUserNames(names) {
   ...
}
```

In the functional style as in your attempt, using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) the parameter is the left side of the arrow function declaration

```
const validUserNames = (names) => { the function body };
```

Then you use the parameter "names" in the place where your global "arr" is used.

As noted in the linked documentation, the parentheses around the parameter are not strictly necessary (depending on the arguments) so your function your wrote with the addition of a parameter to take the place of the global becomes this:

```js
const validUserNames = names => names.filter(s => s.length < 10);

console.log( validUserNames(['tim','tom','taaaaaaxxxxxxmy']) );
console.log( validUserNames(['verylongname', 'fred', 'anothertoolongname', 'jeff']) );
```